# createWebPage returns 'Another entity already exists with the same name'

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to GAS and following the Enterprise Application Essentials book in the Create Web Pages chapter.  The Site class createWebPage method returns "Another entity already exists with the same name", even when I run it in a little snipet as follows:

```
function test () {
  var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl("https://sites.google.com/site/mysite"); 
  var page = site.createWebPage("xxx","xxx","<p>");
}
```

When debugging, I get the error as soon as I step into the method so I can't see where it's happening.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try [getAllDescendants()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_site?hl=fr-FR#getAllDescendants) to check if the page exists or not.

Comment: Thanks Serge.  getAllDescendants returns an array of existing pages, so the script does see my site.

Comment: I think what Serge said was you use the getAllDescendants() call and if your page already exists, then use it instead of creating a new one